# AssertionError at /accounts/tcresults

Tags: python, html, django

I got an error,
AssertionError at /accounts/tcresults
No exception message supplied     .
I wrote in tc.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Score</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Score</h1>
    <h2>Your Score is
    　{{ tcresults.tc }}
      {{ value1 = tcresults.tc
         if value1 > 5000:
       　 <h2>Good</h2>
        　elseif value1 < 900:
          <h2>Bad</h2>
       }}

    </h2>
</body>
</html>
```

in views.py

```
def tc(request):
    tcresults = ImageAndUser.objects.filter(user=request.user).order_by('id').last()
    d = {
        'tcresults': tcresults,
    }
    return render(request, 'registration/accounts/tc.html', d)
```

I cannot understand why this error happen.
What should I do to fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your html, you should do:

```
<h2>Your score is {{ tcresults.tc }}</h2>
{% if tcresults.tc > 5000 %}
    <h2>Good</h2>
{% elif tcresults.tc < 900 %}
    <h2>Bad</h2>
{% endif %}
```

`{{ }}` are used for evaluating variables, while `{% %}` are used for flow control.

Comment: thx, ur comments.I wrote ur code, but the number of "Your Score is"  became blank.What should I do?

Comment: thx！！The part of Your score is ~ is shown, but if statements(it include Good & Bad) is not shown.What should I do to fix this?

Comment: Maybe the value of `tcresults.tc` is between 900 and 5000.